# Can I replace a lost wishbone nut with any similar sized nut?

Tags: suspension, bolts, springs

On my car the rear wishbone(holds the coil spring) attaches to the axel bushes via a long bolt and on the other side an 18mm nut.

I've lost the nut can I replace it with any 18mm nut or does it have to be an exact part number. Taking into account this joint will experience a lot of force etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use just any nut that has the same size and thread, you have to make sure it has the same or better mechanical properties as the original, and by this I mean type of metal, grade of metal, locking/non-locking, etc. Suspension components take a beating, the most sure-fire way to get the right bolt is to order the oem part, which will have a part number. If you can't find that information an auto parts store counter should know what you need.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say, it's a fair point that it didn't come out @Martin. I've re-written.